# Question regarding function field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I have learned in my algebraic curves class that the function field is
the field of rational functions on a curve $C$ (or some variety).

I was at a number theory talk, where the person counted the number of solutions in 
$\mathbb{F}_q[t]$ of certain polynomial equations over $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$ and
was calling it the "function field" setting.

I was wondering if they have the same name because there is some relation?
or is it just a coincidence that they both call it the function field?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a standard analogy in this area between number fields (finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$) on the one hand and function fields (finite extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$) on the other, going back I think to Weil. One keyword here is "three columns," although I think "number field function field analogy" might be a better search term. I think if someone says "function field setting" they're activating this analogy.

Comment: The analogy is pursued IMHO quite nicely in Michael Rosen's book *Number Theory in Function Fields*. Many a result is actually simpler on the function field side.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the helpful comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the actual etymology, but it is true that $\mathbf{F}_q(t)$ is the field of rational functions on the affine line $\mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{F}_q}^1$.